# Port 25 / 26 says "Could not open connection" using Telnet

Tags: email, iis, smtp, localhost, telnet

I am currently troubleshooting an email problem with my server (IIS 7,5 , Windows server 2008 R2). When I run the "Telnet" command, I get the "Connecting to 127.0.0.1... Could not open the connection to the host, on port 25".

I've been running the commands:

- "telnet 127.0.0.1 25"
- "telnet 127.0.0.1 26"
- "telnet localhost 25"
- "telnet localhost 26"

All of these return the same message. If I run at port 80, I get a response.

I tried to turn off my firewall, which made no changes to the behavior (still could not open...).

Is this the usual behavior? Should sending emails still work, or are there something wrong?

Comment: have you confirmed that exchange is running?

Comment: Exchange? I've a clean server install.. Do you need exchange to send emails from a simple server?. I use an external mail server by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 25 is for an MTA (message transfer agent) which passes email along as it goes from sender to recipient.  If you don't have one installed and running locally then there is nothing listening on that local port.  That sounds like the case.

*Sending* email is an outgoing connection (using some random local port) that can be done by connecting to an MTA on any machine accessible via the network; it doesn't have to use one on the local machine.